# How to customize fonts in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor, rich-text-editor

Does anyone know how to customize (add or remove) fonts in the CKEditor 3.x series? I looked all over and I can't figure out how. Supposedly there is a /plugin/fonts folder but it does not exist in 3.5+ of CKEditor.

Comment: just trying to add fonts to the menu, like webdings

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The fonts in the font menu are configured using [`CKEDITOR.config.font_names`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.font_names):

> `<static> {String} CKEDITOR.config.font_names`
>
> The list of fonts names to be displayed in the Font combo in the toolbar. [...]

So all you need to do is set `font_names` in your configuration to the font names you want, for example:

```
config.font_names =
    'Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
    'Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;' +
    'Verdana';
```

Will give you these font names in the menu:

- Arial
- Times New Roman
- Verdana

Comment: thanks. in addition i added CKEDITOR.config.font_names so i get all of them, eg. config.font_names = CKEDITOR.config.font_names + "NewFont"