# Adding fonts available in CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393382/how-to-customize-fonts-in-ckeditor). But I can't seem to get it to work.

In /ckeditor/_source/plugins/font/plugin.js, I have:

```
CKEDITOR.config.font_names =
  'Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
  'Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;' +
  'Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;' +
  'Georgia/Georgia, serif;' +
  'Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;' +
  'Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;' +
  'Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;' +
  'Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
  'Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif';
```

And I just added a new line:

```
  'Calibri/Calibri, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;' +
```

I have hard-refreshed the page, but I am not getting the new "Calibri" font in the drop down. Am I supposed to be doing something else?

Thanks!

Comment: where did you add it? At the end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change the _source files as they aren't used in production.

Use any of the documented methods to change configuration values: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Setting_Configurations

Comment: ok, think i got it.
i just added that entire block to the config file.
is that the best way?

Comment: If you want that configuration for every CKEditor instance, then yes, that's might be the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

never change `_source` files!

use `config.js` to alter your configuration

eg:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.font_names =
            'Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
            'Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;' +
            'Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;' +
            'Georgia/Georgia, serif;' +
            'Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;' +
            'Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;' +
            'Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;' +
            'Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
            'Calibri/Calibri, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;' + /* here is your font */
            'Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif';

   // here you can add more config.*
};
```